# Iterating over columns of database tables using entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a database which needs to be cleaned, yet I want to clean it dynamically. Each Table contains several fields and my requirement is that the "`Trim()`" function be applied to all "String" fields.

Suppose I have two tables named `CustomerInfo` and `CustomerPayments`, My requirement is to first iterate over these tables and for each table, search for columns (fields) that have type of "`String`" and then apply the `Trim()` method to them.

Can I do that with LINQ?

I was using the following code to no avail since the `CustomerInfo` class generated by Entity Framework does not implements `GetProperties()`.

```
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in CustomerInfo.GetProperties())
```

Though I am truly in need of iterating table names in the base entity object as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't this be

```
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in typeof(CustomerInfo).GetProperties())
```

?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How about extracting tables, based on your solution I did the following: foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in typeof(AdventureWorksLT2008Entities).GetProperties())
            {if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.BaseType.Name.StartsWith("ObjectQuery"))
                {
                    //This is a table, Do Something
                }}

Comment: I haven't touched the EF for some time but googling for "entity framework enumerate tables" yields some interesting results.